# How to transfer letsencrypt SSL certificates from EC2 to Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, aws-fargate

We have a few SSL certificates with NGINX config that we have in our EC2 for our hosts and subdomains. We are eager to create separate containers for our repositories and manage them using ECS and Fargate.  I don't really have a solid idea about how to make the transfer work and what are the best practices for this? We can't afford any downtime or SSL errors during the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [best option](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/) is to run fargate behind the [Load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/service-load-balancing.html), as Load balancer sense the health of fargate services or EC2 type ECS services and distribute traffic based on load or services health.

LB support TLS termination that terminates before sending to the target.

Then why you should manage TLS at container level?

[image]

In this [architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/maintaining-transport-layer-security-all-the-way-to-your-container-using-the-network-load-balancer-with-amazon-ecs/), the containers in each of the clusters can reference the other containers securely via the Network Load Balancer without terminating or offloading the certificates until it reaches the destination container.

So you have two option at Load balancer level.

- Application LB
- Network LB
  Both will work same but ALB work at the Application layer and Network work at network level both can work in your case.

So  I will suggest importing your certificate to LB.

1. Import certificate
2. Create ALB
3. Add https listener
4. Select imported Certificate
5. Create fargate service and attached with LB port 443
6. Check with some testing DNS with SSL
7. Update your DNS record to point NEW infra without downtime.

https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home?region=us-west-2#/importwizard/

[image]

If you want with in service then you need to add in your docker file. But the above is best approach as per knowledge.

Comment: Thank you it makes total sense. I'm just wondering if LB can handle wildcard certificates for subdomains as well? I can have unlimited subdomains that all the traffic for that will go to a specific container

Comment: Yes LB can handle wildcard certificate, btw its depend on certificates on LB